# Split the decimal number in half

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this algorithm, and it's not working. This should split the number in half:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m = 0, k = 0, p = 0, i = 0, y, r = 0, s = 0, j = 0;

    cin >> y;

    n = y;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        k++;
    }

    if (k % 2 == 0){
        m = k / 2;
        p = k / 2;
    }
    else {
        m = k / 2;
        p = (k / 2) + 1;
    }

    n = y;

    while (r < p){
        i = n % 10 * pow(10, r) + i;
        r++;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    while (s < m){
        j = n % 10 * pow(10, s) + j;
        s++;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    cout << j << " " << i;
}
```

**Algorithm:** `y` is the number you read, `n` is where I save `y` because it can be lost in the loop, `k` is a variable where I number how many digits does the number has.

For number 13584, it is working:

[image]

But for number 123456789, it isn't.

[image]

Comment: Code with single letter variable names is *really* hard to read. Can't you give the variables meaningful names? Also, paste the output as text, instead of images. Also please run your code through a formatter. e.g. http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text as text into the question. Also, what do you mean by "split the number in half"? For some specific input what should the output be? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, please learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Sure, y-is the number you read, n- is where I save y because it can be lost in the loop , k- is a variable where I number how many digits does the number has,

Comment: Convert the number to a string.  IMHO, digits are easier to manipulate when the number is a string.

Comment: [The error isn't reproducible.](http://cpp.sh/3qwln) Tell us a bit about your compiler and environment, it'll be easier to solve the error (if any).

Comment: you put the same screen shot twice

Answer (score -3):

Everything is working. Here is your code changed.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int n, m = 0, k = 0, p = 0, i = 0, y, r = 0, s = 0, j = 0;

    cout << "Enter number to split ";
    cin >> y;

    n = y;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        k++;
    }

    if (k % 2 == 0)
    {
        p = m = k / 2;

    }

    else {
        p=m = k / 2;
        p++;
    }

    n = y;

    while (r < p) {
        i = n % 10 * pow(10, r) + i; 
        r++; 
        n = n / 10;
    }

    while (s < m) { j = n % 10 * pow(10, s) + j; s++; n = n / 10; }

    cout << j << " " << i;

}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer and code only answers teach people to be [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You can salvage this answer by explaining what was wrong with the original code and how this new code corrects the problem.

Comment: It is working on my computer but I have not found the problem. So I posted the code.

Comment: @Alex Your code is logically the same as the original code. The only thing you changed was merging the assignments of `p` and `m` in the `if..else` blocks, but the end result of those assignments should be the same as the original code.